# Не изменяется content в label:before

Tags: html, css

При нажатии на checkbox, не меняется content с + (плюс) на - (минус). Как это исправить?

```css
.hide {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
label.clickme {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}

label.clickme:before {  
    content: '+'; 
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: green;
    color: #fff;
}
label.clickme:before + input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
    content: '-';
}
```

```html
<label class='clickme' for='h'>Метка</label>
<input type='checkbox' class='hide' id='h'>
```

Comment: Как минимум, вы написали `content: '-'` не для label, а для input

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте местами теги, чтобы label был после input:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='hide' id='h'>
<label class='clickme' for='h'>Метка</label>
```

В CSS пишите так:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label.clickme:before{
  content: '-';
}
```

Comment: не могу поменять местами label и input, так как тогда не будет работать другой css стиль, а именно при нажатии на label появляется div блок, при повторном нажатии исчезает: 
.spoiler >  input + .box { display: none; }
.spoiler >  input:checked + .box { display: block; }

<div class='spoiler'>
<label></label>
<input>
<div class='box'></div>
</div>

Или уже тут надо менять код